# How can I make django model in this situation?

Tags: python, django

I make a stock market project using django.
So I want to make 2 database table.

1. table stocklist (ticker, name)
2. table stockPrice (code, date, price, open, high, close etc...)

I want to make second table name is stock ticker.
so I though this is many to one relation. And I made django model.py

```
class StockList(models.Model):
    ticker= models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

class stockPrice(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey('stockList', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    open = models.FloatField()      
    high =models.FloatField()      
    low = models.FloatField()       
    close = models.FloatField()     
    diff = models.FloatField()  
    volume = models.FloatField()
```

But it isn't work. How I make django model? And is it many to one relation?
Thank you.

---

I want to make DB like this. So Am I make all class in models.py?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gquie.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work". Can you post the error message, or the exact unexpected behavior if there is no error

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you. I don't speak english well. It's work. But it is not way I thought. I want to use ticker as the table name. So should I create all class in model.py?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how it works differently form you expect?

Comment: I want to use ticker as the table name.(ex. table tsla, table FB, table NFLX) So should I create all class in model.py?

Comment: You can use the model meta to change the name of the table in the database, if that is what you want. Though I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thank you! And I edit my post with image. Can you see it and help me?

Answer (score 0):

In class `stockPrice`, try to replace:

```py
ticker = models.ForeignKey('stockList', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with:

```py
ticker = models.ForeignKey(StockList, to_field='ticker', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to make each stock table(ex. table name are tesla table, netflix table)  , that way is wrong?